# Barplot colour parameter overrides fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the outline colour of a bar plot but every time I set colour it completely fills the bar plot.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=depth))+geom_bar(stat='identity',fill="#FF9999")
```

The above code works fine returns a pink plot but when I wan to add a black outline around each bar. Like so..

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=depth))+geom_bar(stat='identity',fill="#FF9999", colour='black')
```

Every barplot turns completely black. I modified the sample code from page 21 from R Graphics Cookbook (O'Reilly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my comments together make a decent answer:

With the default position = "stack", what you're doing is plotting a bunch of tiny little bars on top of each other, which you can see with

```
ggplot(diamonds[1:100, ], aes(x=clarity, y = depth)) +
    geom_bar(fill="#FF9999", colour='black', stat = "identity")
```

With most barplots, you only specify an x-variable to get the counts on the y

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity)) +
    geom_bar(fill="#FF9999", colour='black')
```

If you want to summarize depth for each value of clarity, I'd use `dplyr`. (I never got the hang of `stat_summary` which is the ggplot way to do it.)

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% group_by(clarity) %>% 
  summarize(mean_depth = mean(depth)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = clarity, y = mean_depth)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#FF9999", colour = "black")
```